# How to create a follower/following icon react/redux

Tags: reactjs, mongoose, webpack, redux, react-router

I already set up a many to many relationship sort of like social network. The problem I am facing is to create a single icon that can detect if user is already connected and if they are the follow icon should change to followed icon instead.

This is the piece of code which will decide whether to render which type of icon (either follower or following).

```
ConnectionHandle(Array, _id){
  return Array.map(function(el, index){
      console.log('chicken');
    if(el === User_id){
      return(
        <div className="btn btn-warning" onClick={() => this.props.disconnectUser({id: _id})}>- user</div>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <div className="btn btn-info" onClick={() => this.props.connectUser({id: _id})}>+ user</div>
      );
    }
  },this);
};
```

The above code will be within an li list below:

```
return this.props.users.map(function(el, index){
    return (
      <li className="list-group-item" key={ index }>
        <Link to={`/users/${el._id}`} activeClassName="active">
         {el.email}
         <div className="pull-sm-right">Join on    {this.joinDate(el.createdAt)}</div>
         {this.entryNum(el.entries.length)}
         {this.userNum(el.followers.length)}
         <div>{el.follow.length} follows</div>
       </Link>
       {this.ConnectionHandle(el.followers, el._id)}
      </li>
    )
  }, this)
}
```

The backend is tested with postman is it works as expected in establishing many to many relationship. Their relationship will also be update with lifecycle method.

I just need the missing piece to convert icons from follow back to followed and vice versa.

Comment: Which icon are you referring to? Also you should avoid to name a variable `Array`, as it conceals the built-in [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: oh ok i wasn't sure of that. I named it conventionally. In any case, I wish to create a button element that will toggle between '+ user' and '- user' text whenever user click it.

I'm trying to build a personal side project to understand the dynamics of social network when you stitch backend to frontend. The button should somewhat behaves like 'add friend' of facebook after user click and mongoose updates db, the new state should reflect that change. @AnthonyGarcia .

Comment: any advice would be appreciated. I have been googling for answers for quite a while and I really want to bring this feature to life.  @AnthonyGarcia . Thanks in advance.

I attached the link to my repo in case if anyone wants a slightly clearer picture. everything is in public folder.

Github repo: https://github.com/boyboi86/API_basic_random